# Terraform json/map conversion in dynamic section

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to configure a specific list of user with terraform in a dynamic section.

First, I have all my users / password as a json in a Vault like this:

```
{
    "user1": "longPassword1",
    "user2amq": "longPassword2",
    "user3": "longPassword3"
}
```

then I declare the Vault data with

```
data "vault_kv_secret_v2" "all_clients" {
  provider  = my.vault.provider
  mount     = "credentials/aws/amq"
  name      = "dev/clients"
}
```

and in a `locals` section:

```
locals {
    all_clients = tomap(jsondecode(data.vault_kv_secret_v2.all_clients.data.client_list))
}
```

in my tf file, I declare the dynamic section like this:

```
dynamic "user" {
    for_each = local.all_clients

    content {
      username = each.key
      password = each.value
      console_access = "false"
      groups = ["users"]
    }
}
```

When I apply my terraform I got an error:

```
│   on modules/amq/amq.tf line 66, in resource "aws_mq_broker" "myproject":
│   66:     for_each = local.all_clients
│
│ Cannot use a map of string value in for_each. An iterable collection is
│ required.
```

I tried many ways to manage such a map but always terminating with an error

(like using `=` instead `:` and bypassing the jsondecode, or having a Map or a List of Object with
"username": "user1"
"pasword": "pass1"

etc... (I am open to adjust the Json for making it working)

Nothing was working and I am a bit out of idea how to map such a simple thing into terraform. I already check plenty of questions/answers in SO and none are working for me.

Terraform version 1.3.5

UPDATE:

By just putting an output on the local variable outside my module:

```
locals {
    all_clients = jsondecode(data.vault_kv_secret_v2.all_clients.data.client_list)
}

output all_clients {
    value = local.all_clients
}
```

after I applied the code, the command `terraform output -json all_clients` will show my json structure properly (and same if I put `=` instead and just displayed as a map, without the `jsondecode`).

As the answer says, the issue is more related to sensitiveness while declaring the loop.

On the other side, I had to adjust my username not being emails because not supported by AWS AmazonMQ (ActiveMQ) and password field must be greater than 12 chars (max 250 chars).

Comment: What is the value of `data.vault_kv_secret_v2.all_clients.data.client_list`?

Comment: `data.vault_kv_secret_v2.all_clients` is already a HCL2 `map(string)` type, and so the `tomap` and `jsondecode` functions are unnecessary. Also the mount and secret structure in Vault both appear unusual, and that may be causing issues when Read in the TF resource.

Comment: @Marcin the Vault contains a secret `client_list` with the json above.

Comment: @MattSchuchard It was not clear to me what string structure is a HCL2 map because in tfvars I have to declare it as `{ "key1" = "value1", "key2" = "value2", etc... } but in both case it does not work in the dynamic (I removed the jsondecode if i use `=`instead of `:`.).
If I remove tomap, I got error: " Cannot use a string value in for_each. An iterable collection is required."

Comment: Ok I think this will probably be fixed if you store the KV2 secret normally instead of as a JSON formatted string as an extension to my previous comment.

Comment: thanks MattSchuchard and Marcin for your comments. At the end it was more an issue with sensitive data and not the format of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is something Terraform doesn't support but isn't explaining well: you can't use a map that is marked as sensitive directly as the `for_each` expression, because doing so would disclose some information about that sensitive value in a way that Terraform can't hide in the UI. At the very least, it would expose the number of elements.

It seems like in this particular case it's overly conservative to consider the entire map to be sensitive, but neither Vault nor Terraform understand the meaning of your data structure and so are treating the whole thing as sensitive just to make sure nothing gets disclosed accidentally.

Assuming that only the passwords in this result are actually sensitive, I think the best answer would be to specify explicitly what is and is not sensitive using the `sensitive` and `nonsensitive` functions to override the very coarse sensitivity the `hashicorp/vault` provider is generating:

```
locals {
  all_clients = tomap({
    for user, password in jsondecode(nonsensitive(data.vault_kv_secret_v2.all_clients.data.client_list)) :
    user => sensitive(password)
  })
}
```

Using `nonsensitive` always requires care because it's overriding Terraform's automatic inference of sensitive values and so if you use it incorrectly you might show sensitive information in the Terraform UI.

In this case I first used `nonsensitive` on the whole JSON string returned by the `vault_kv_secret_v2` data source, which therefore avoids making the `jsondecode` result wholly sensitive. Then I used the `for` expression to carefully mark just the passwords as sensitive, so that the final value would -- if assigned to somewhere that causes it to appear in the UI -- appear like this:

```
tomap({
  "user1" = (sensitive value)
  "user2amq" = (sensitive value)
  "user3" = (sensitive value)
})
```

Now that the number of elements in the map and the map's keys are no longer sensitive, this value should be compatible with the `for_each` in a dynamic block just like the one you showed. Because the value of each element is sensitive, Terraform will treat the `password` argument value *in particular* as sensitive, while disclosing the email addresses.

If possible I would suggest testing this with fake data that isn't really sensitive first, just to make sure that you don't accidentally expose real sensitive data if anything here isn't quite correct.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, you lead me to the right path. 
I finally use the solution 1 in this [page](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4538432032787-Variable-has-a-sensitive-value-and-cannot-be-used-as-for-each-arguments) by just looping over the key set and taking the all_users[user.key] for the password field which stay sensitive.